# Is there a (free) windows test/dummy print device?

Tags: windows, printing, testing, device

We are creating a batch application which sends its documents (Java Jasperreports) directly to a printer device, running on a Windows server.

To test the application and measure the performace, we where looking for a test or dummy windows print device. This device would not print to an actual printer but simulate a printer device in such a way that its buffer, number of pages printed per minute etc. can be configured and a report on the number of printed pages can be generated.

The only test devices found on the web print to pdf files, but a system as described seems hard to find. Does it exist?

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google found this: http://www.mabuse.de/tech-vprinter.mhtml

Comment: Did find these kind of devices, indeed, but they don't tell much about performance, printer buffer status etc.

Comment: @Jurgen: I see they come with source, maybe they are a good start for your quite precise requirements, if you find no other solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it'll give you all the reporting you want, but you can pause any installed printer on Windows, and it'll just spool the jobs to the queue without sending anything to the actual printer.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe PDF Printer